# Drupal 8 - Submit Webform to an external API

Tags: api, drupal, drupal-8

I have a Webform on my Drupal website(8.8.5). The Webform has multiple fields along with two file fields.

When the user submits the Webform, I want to send the details to an external API (SugarCRM) including the files attached in the Webform.

How can I do this? Is there a module available in Drupal 8 to achieve this easily? Or do I need to handle the data submitted and call the API manually?

I also would like to store the data on the website as it works usually.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I believe [Webform SugarCRM Integration](https://www.drupal.org/project/webform_sugarcrm) may be just what you are after. It has a stable release `8.x-2.1` for Drupal 8.

If it doesn't suit your needs, you could write your own custom Webform handler. Something like the below, extending Webform's `WebformHandlerBase` class:

```
<?php

namespace Drupal\your_module\Plugin\WebformHandler;

use Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerBase;

/**
 * Class SugarCrmWebformHandler.
 *
 * @package Drupal\your_module\Plugin\WebformHandler
 *
 * @WebformHandler(
 *   id = "sugar_crm",
 *   label = @Translation("Sugar CRM"),
 *   category = @Translation("External"),
 *   description = @Translation("Webform handler integrating with Sugar CRM."),
 *   cardinality = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::CARDINALITY_SINGLE,
 *   results = \Drupal\webform\Plugin\WebformHandlerInterface::RESULTS_PROCESSED,
 * )
 */
class SugarCrmWebformHandler extends WebformHandlerBase {

  /**
   * {@inheritdoc}
   */
  public function postSave(WebformSubmissionInterface $webform_submission, $update = TRUE) {
    # code for Sugar CRM...
  }

}
```

Alternatively you could also look into using Webform's `RemotePostWebformHandler` class which may provide some boilerplate for your integration.

See additional resources:

- [Webform Cookbook](https://www.drupal.org/docs/8/modules/webform/webform-cookbook)
- [Create a custom webform handler in Drupal 8](https://industrialagency.ca/blog/create-custom-webform-handler-drupal-8)

Comment: Great. This worked well as expected for all the other field. But, do you know how to upload a file from Drupal website to SugarCRM.